# Errors in PHP OOP class about connection and login

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am following an online course about PHP and I have to solve an exercise which transforming a procedural script into OOP. The script is about connecting using PDO into MySQL and create a class to connect and login.

I have this class to create a connection into db:

```
var $db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass, $connection;



function __construct($host = "localhost", $name="sigmas", $user="root", $pass="ithss")
{
    $this->db_host = $host;
    $this->db_name = $name;

    $this->db_user = $user;
    $this->db_pass = $pass;
}

public function connect()
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $connection;
}

function login($conn, $user, $pass, $msg='')
{
    $this->conn = $connetion;

    $this->username = $user;
    $this->password = $pass;
    if($username == "" || $password == "")
    {
        $this->msg = "Please add user name and password";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = :user";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':user', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if($result)
        {
            if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
            {
                session_start();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    if(password_verify($password, $row['pass']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['role'] = $row['user_role'];
                        header("Location: index.php");              
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: wrong.php");
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to include it in my login page:

```
include('classes.php');

if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
{
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];

    $log = new myClass();
    $log->connect();
    $log->login($conn, $username, $password, $msg);
}
```

And here is my HTML form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="login_btn" type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

But I am having those errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db_host in classes.php
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: db_name in classes.php
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: connetion in classes.php
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username in classes.php

Comment: `$conn` from connection function and $msg is a property that I will access it later in the same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line in your `connect()` method,

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

The variables `$db_host`, `$db_name`, `$db_user` and `db_pass` are not available in the scope of your method.

So your `connect()` method should be like this:

```
public function connect()
{
    $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $this->connection;
}
```

### Update:

First of all, always start session at the very top of your PHP scripts, like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // your code
```

Then, declare necessary instance variables and instead of using `password_verify()` function, create a `private` instance method to verify the password, like this:

```
private function password_verify($user_pass, $orig_pass){

    // Compare user's password with the original password

}
```

**So the solution is:**

Keep your HTML form as it is. And after submitting, process your form like this:

```
session_start();
include('classes.php');

if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])){
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];

    $log = new myClass();
    $log->connect();
    if($log->login($username, $password)){

        // Login successful
        // redirect the user to a different page
        header("Location: process.php");
        exit();

    }else{
        // Incorrect username and/or password
        // display error message
        echo $log->msg;
    }
}
```

And here's the modified **myClass** class,

```
class myClass{

    private $db_host;
    private $db_name; 
    private $db_user;
    private $db_pass;
    private $connection;
    public $msg;

    function __construct($host = "localhost", $name="sigmas", $user="root", $pass="ithss"){
        $this->db_host = $host;
        $this->db_name = $name;
        $this->db_user = $user;
        $this->db_pass = $pass;
    }

    public function connect(){
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function login($user, $pass){
        if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
            $this->msg = "Please fill the credentials";
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = :user LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            if($result){
                $row = array_shift($result);
                if($this->password_verify($pass, $row['pass'])){
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['user_role'];
                    return true;                    
                }else{
                    $this->msg = "Incorrect username and/or password";
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                $this->msg = "Incorrect username and/or password";
                return false;
                //header("Location: wrong.php");
            }
        }
    }

    private function password_verify($user_pass, $orig_pass){

        // Compare user's password with the original password

    }

}
```

Comment: New error: `Notice: Undefined variables: connetion and username in classes.php`

Comment: @LaraCh In this line `$log->login($conn, $username, $password, $msg);` from where did you get `$conn` and `$msg` values? Also, there's no member variable named `$username`, `$password`, `$msg` and `$conn` in your class. Check these things first.

Comment: `$conn` is from connect() method, `$username` and `$password` are set from posted values from the form

Comment: @LaraCh There are several things wrong here. See your `login()` method, can you see these lines here, `$this->conn = $connetion;`, `$this->username = $user;` and `$this->password = $pass;`? where did you declare those instance variables? Also, see this line `$log->login($conn, $username, $password, $msg);` from where did you get `$conn` and `$msg` values? Fix these things first.

Comment: @LaraCh And since you've declared an instance variable as `$connection`, it's better if you assign the connection to *that* instance variable and subsequently return that instance variable. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @LaraCh I've updated my answer. Please see the **update** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
```

use `$this->db_user` and `$this->db_pass` like  :

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
```